# AMD, second monitor not displaying properly

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, xrandr, amd-graphics

I've recently run into a problem with my second monitor on Ubuntu 14.04.
Only a slither of it actually displays anything, it's not a faulty monitor as I've switched the DVI cables and the problem persists on separate monitors.

It only happens to one monitor. I've tried messing around with the `.xprofile` and made this.

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 3360x1050 --rate 60

xrandr --output DVI-0

xrandr --output DVI-0 --primary
```

And when I log in the output is.

```
Error found when loading /home/user/.xprofile

warning: output DVI-0 not found, ignoring.
xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 1680x1680 (desired size 3360x1050)
warning: output DVI-0 not found, ignoring.
xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 1680x1680 (desired size 3360x1050)
warning: output DVI-0 not found, ignoring.
xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 1680x1680 (desired size 3360x1050)

As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
```

That is the output. I assume I'm just not specifying the right display or I've written the "code" wrong.

If anyone can rewrite this or provide support in general that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you upload the output of `xrandr; echo; xrandr --verbose` to http://paste.ubuntu.com . Does this mode 3360x1050 work when you set it directly (not with .xprofile)?